# Spring Data Rest - Embedded entity not deserialized on POST

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I have a spring data rest project set up with Persistence entities `Employer` and `Employee`. `Employee` has a `@ManyToOne` relationship defined to `Employer` as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Employer employer;
    ...
}
```

This works well when I have a unit test persisting an `Employee` that has within it an `Employer` object. However, when I submit a POST request with a JSON body to my endpoint, I notice that the deserialized `Employer` information is null...

```
TRACE 16948 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Arguments: [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation@71b498f9, Resource { content: Employee [id=1, ename=John, surname=Snow, jobTitle=Crow, companyName=Wall, companyContact=Warden of North, employeeNumber=, costCentre=, employer=null], links: [] }, org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler@5e618dcb, */*]
```

This tells me that my `Employee` JSON isn't being deserialized correctly. Is there some config I need to add to get this to happen automatically, or do I need to create my own deserializer to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as there's still no answer :) I did the workaround as discussed in the question - I created a custom deserializer.